# Dell Perc5/E not recognized in Dell Poweredge 1950

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I'have ordered new Dell Perc5/E and new PCIe risers to my server Dell Poweredge 1950 III. I am trying to connect MD1000 to the server, but the server does not recognize Perc5/E, nothing to see in boot setup and on Dell OpenManage what I see is:

```
Slot ID Adapter Data Bus Width  
PCI1    [Not Occupied]  8x or x8    
PCI2    [Not Occupied]  8x or x8    
Embedded    5000X Chipset Memory Controller Hub N/A 
Embedded    Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE (LOM)   N/A 
Embedded    SAS 6/iR Integrated RAID Controller N/A 
Embedded    5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 4-5 N/A 
Embedded    5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 5   N/A 
Embedded    5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 6-7 N/A 
Embedded    5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 7   N/A 
Embedded    Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE (LOM)   N/A 
Embedded    631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #1 N/A 
Embedded    631xESB/632xESB IDE Controller  N/A 
Embedded    6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Downstream Port E2  N/A 
Embedded    Radeon Graphics Adapter N/A 
Embedded    Remote Access Controller 5  N/A
```

I am using Debian 6.0.6, could someone suggest me where could be the problem? Or should I install something to the server to detect Perc5/e ? The green led on perc is on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by moving the card up to drac5 card - to PCI1 (second slot from the power supply), showed in bios, CTRL-R to configurate. lspci and dell omsa also showed the card in the PCI1!